# How use Custom container with XML DSL

Tags: citrus-framework

I need to use a custom container to implement iterative action execution over a collection of objects in the XML Citrus test.

There's a nice Custom container documentation, however XML DSL is not explained there.

The custom conteiner is like this:
public class CollectionIterationContainer extends AbstractActionContainer /*...*/

Is it possible to use the Custom container in the XML DSL at all? If yes - how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally doable. The second part of this article describes how to get custom actions or containers into the XML testcase:

https://citrusframework.org/docs/custom-actions/